Issue with regular expression test method
const regex = new RegExp('\D{3}');
var text = "foo";

console.log(regex.test(text));

Why does this evaluate to false?

Because there is no DDD in your input string that your regex is trying to find. Use const regex = /\D{3}/ or const regex = new RegExp('\\D{3}').
